# Can somebody explain difference between this 2 reference usages in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, reference, tree

The code below illustrates the strange behaviour of PHP references:

```
<?php

function this_works()
{
    $root = array('name'=>'root', 'children'=>array());
    $level_1 = array('name'=>'level_1', 'children'=>array());
    $item1 = array('name'=>'level_2_1', 'children'=>array());
    $item2 = array('name'=>'level_2_2', 'children'=>array());

    $croot = &$root;

    $croot['children'][] = &$level_1;

    $croot = &$level_1;

    $croot['children'][] = &$item1;
    $croot['children'][] = &$item2;

    $croot = &$root;

    print_r($croot);
}    

function this_fails()
{    
    $root = array('name'=>'root', 'children'=>array());
    $level_1 = array('name'=>'level_1', 'children'=>array());
    $item1 = array('name'=>'level_2_1', 'children'=>array());
    $item2 = array('name'=>'level_2_2', 'children'=>array());
    $croot = &$root;

    $stack = array();

    $croot['children'][] = &$level_1;
    $crootref = &$croot;

    array_push($stack, $crootref);

    $croot = &$level_1;

    $croot['children'][] = &$item1;
    $croot['children'][] = &$item2;

    # this works, assignment below - doesn't... WHY?
    #$x = array_pop($stack);
    #var_dump($x);

    $croot = array_pop($stack);

    print_r($croot);
}    

this_works();
echo "------------------\n";
this_fails();

?>
```

First function provides expected results,
while the second fails and claims about recursion loop:

```
Array
(
    [name] => root
    [children] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => level_1
                    [children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => level_2_1
                                    [children] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => level_2_2
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                           )

                )

        )

)
------------------
Array
(
    [name] => root
    [children] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => root
                    [children] => Array
 *RECURSION*
                )

    )

)
```

What is strange, is that if in the second function, intermediate
variable will be used to get value from stack, results are OK again.
I don't understand what is going on. How do I get root element as
a child of itself many times due to one assinment?

Originally, I needed to build the tree from XML (using sax parser)
and intented to have 'current root' that points to tree node at
the current level and push/pop it to/from stack and add child elements to it,
but, surprisingly, I failed to implement this scheme due to issues demonstrated
by two functions above.

So, what is wrong with such approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One picture worths 1000 words.
It took some time to understand
what's exactly is going on.

I had to use Xdebug to dump internal
data properly and see refcounts
and effects of copy on write.

The issue with the code in 1st post
is that assignment

$croot = array_pop($stack);

when croot is 'level_1' is done by copy,
i.e. elements of croot (same as level_1)
are populated with data from stack and
croot is not the same as original root after this operation.

The image will explain better.

[image: PHP variables in memory]

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the weird way PHP does references inside arrays. Doing a normal (not by reference) assignment with a reference on the right side does not usually turn the left side into a reference, but references inside arrays **are preserved** in assignments, even without the reference operator.

I've commented your code below to help explain what is happening, I hope I've explained this correctly, it's 1am and I'm getting tired.

```
$root = array('name'=>'root', 'children'=>array());
$level_1 = array('name'=>'level_1', 'children'=>array());
// $croot and $root now point to the same variable
$croot = &$root;

$stack = array();

$croot['children'][] = &$level_1;
// $crootref, $croot and $root all now point to the same variable
$crootref = &$croot;
// $stack[0], $crootref, $croot and $root all now point to the same variable.
// $stack[0]['children'][0], $level_1, $croot['children'][0] point to the same variable
array_push($stack, $crootref);
// $croot, $level_1 and $stack[0]['children'][0] now point to the same variable
// Infinite loop is caused as $stack[0]['children'][0] is now an alias for $croot
// which contains $croot['children'][0] which is an alias for $stack[0]['children'][0]
// which is an alias for $croot which contains....
$croot = &$level_1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a workaround, using unset() instead of array_pop(). And because when you use array_pop() the array pointer of the input array is resseted i use reset() to simulate the same results, here you go:

```
<?php

function this_fails_fixed()
{    
    $root = array('name'=>'root', 'children'=>array());
    $level_1 = array('name'=>'level_1', 'children'=>array());
    $item1 = array('name'=>'level_2_1', 'children'=>array());
    $item2 = array('name'=>'level_2_2', 'children'=>array());
    $croot = &$root;

    $stack = array();

    $croot['children'][] = &$level_1;
    $crootref = &$croot;

    array_push($stack, $crootref);

    $croot = &$level_1;

    $croot['children'][] = &$item1;
    $croot['children'][] = &$item2;

    unset($croot[count($croot)-1]);
        reset($croot);

    print_r($croot);
}    

this_fails_fixed();

?>
```